# Use dropdown selection in URL

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm following the answer [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2f45856b-87a2-4e17-8894-d352a3113ac9/passing-selected-option-from-dropdown-to-controller?forum=aspdotnetcore) to use the selection from a dropdown in a URL. I am using asp.net core, using:

```
asp-page="/Page" asp-page-handler="Action"
```

To do the redirect

The script below (from the link above) works great, except if you select an item from the dropdown then select a different one (and on and on), it appends both to the URL.

```
<script>
$("[name=selectedAnalyst]").on("change", function () {
    var analystId = $(this).val();
    var accept = $(this).closest('td').next().find("a")[0];
    var oldUrl = accept.href;
    var newUrl = oldUrl + "&analystid=" + analystId;
    $(accept).attr("href", newUrl);
})
```

I tried scrubbing the parameter in question (using params.delete) but it's not working:

```
<script>
$("[name=selectedAnalyst]").on("change", function () {
    var analystId = $(this).val();
    var accept = $(this).closest('td').next().find("a")[0];
    var oldUrl = accept.href;
    let params = new URLSearchParams(oldUrl.search);

    params.delete('analystid')
    var newUrl = oldUrl + "&analystid=" + analystId;

    $(accept).attr("href", newUrl);
})
```

Is there a way to get the above script to work how I envision, or a better way to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

it seems that

```
let params = new URLSearchParams(oldUrl.search);

    params.delete('analystid')
```

does not work
I tried with the codes and it could work

```
<script>
        $("[name=selectedAnalyst]").on("change", function () {
            var analystId = $(this).val();
            var accept = $(this).closest('td').next().find("a")[0];
            var oldUrl = accept.href;
            var a = oldUrl.indexOf("analystid");
            console.log(a);
            if (a == -1)
            {
                var newUrl = oldUrl + "&analystid=" + analystId;
            }
            else
            {
                var newUrl= oldUrl.substring(0, oldUrl.length - 1) + analystId;
            }          
            
            console.log(newUrl);
            console.log(oldUrl);           
            $(accept).attr("href", newUrl);
        })
    </script>
```

Comment: That got me most of the way there. It scrubbed the extra &analystid= but it would only scrub the last character from the previous dropdown choice. I used what you started to get there, see my other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Building on what Ruikai Feng posted I think this is working:

```
$("[name=selectedAnalyst]").on("change", function () {
var analystId  = $(this).val();
var accept = $(this).closest('td').next().find("a")[0];
var oldUrl = accept.href;
var a = oldUrl.indexOf("analystId ");
if (a == -1) {
    var newUrl = oldUrl + "&analystId =" + analystId ;
}
else {
    var newUrl = oldUrl.substring(0, a - 1) + "&analystId =" + analystId;
}

$(accept).attr("href", newUrl);
})
```